# Why can't I change my table footer's text color?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When the user gives improper input within a textfield cell of a `UITableView`, I want to change the footer to be a warning with colored text, describing the error. I've gotten it to work perfectly aside from the coloring. **What of my code below am I doing wrong, such that the text is not colored?**

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        // Inspection confirms this case is entered when needed.
        case SECTION_VALIDATABLE_FORM:
        {
            UITableViewHeaderFooterView *warningFooter = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:K_FOOTER_WARNING];
            UIColor *color = [MyColors uiColorForKey:K_COLOR_TEXT_ERROR]; // inspection confirms this is the UIColor equivalent of #BB2222
            [warningFooter.textLabel setTextColor:color];
            return warningFooter;
        }
        // other sections...
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewHeaderFooterView uses a custom UILabel subclass and apparently, the color can't be changed.

You should subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and add your own label manually.

```
@interface XXTableViewHeaderFooterView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *myLabel;
@end


@implementation XXTableViewHeaderFooterView

- (instancetype)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
{
    self = [super initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
        _myLabel.textColor = ...;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_myLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Could I use categories to accomplish this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can't add a property with a category.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused... you hadn't mentioned `@property`s, and can I not just create a category with an overridden getter? Also, what property must I override? `label`?

Comment: As I said UITableViewHeaderFooterView uses a private subclass of UILabel, a category won't work. Just create a subclass, I added you the boilerplate code.

Comment: so why can't I made an `@implementation UITableViewHeaderFooterView (MyFooterHeaderView)` with a `-(UILabel*)textLabel` that just returns my custom label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87518/discussion-between-ben-c-r-leggiero-and-deadbeef).

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into my project and used that class instead of mine. It still renders as grey text.

Comment: here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5F-QovDhUozQU9POEswWGJmRlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well you need to use myLabel and not textLabel now in tableView:viewForFooterInSection: